# Row not expanding to full width of columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Context, my page is divided like so:

- Left hand side (col-xs-8)
- Right hand side (col-xs-4)

The right hand side should remain fixed and not scroll (there are some elements on the left hand side that need scrolling). The right hand side has the following code:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
```

The problem is that the row doesn't seem to expand the full width of the `col-xs-4`, and I'm not sure why. If I try to add a `width:100%` style on the row, it seems to go crazy and expand to a normal browser window even though it's nested within a `col-xs-4`. And the reason this is a problem by the way is that the table needs to be wider than it is because now it's completely illegible.

I've been doing some troubleshooting but am stuck. It looks like the problem is that the `col-xs-4` is not even "registering" on the page. If you do an inspect element, the `col-xs-8` of the left hand side is visible, but the `col-xs-4` is not, which indicates that the `col-xs-8` isn't closed, but I've looked everywhere and it is....

Anyways, would love help, here's the working staging environment link since this is a little hard to explain: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/request

Comment: Your link redirects to a page that does not have a left/right column layout.

Comment: pls do not ask your questions twice

Comment: @RachelGallen I haven't asked a question twice....

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister the left is the light gray + white section, the right is the dark gray. I checked the link

Comment: @james your q here and the other one are identical

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm sorry, I'm not understanding how... this one is about width not being 100%. That one is about position:fixed not working

Comment: which you have also mentioned here

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm sorry... I may have mentioned things contextually, but for me, I totally read these questions entirely differently. Rather than having a discussion about this, I would love your input in helping find a solution, to close at least one of the quesitons.

Comment: @RachelGallen Please flag the question and provide a link the the other q if you believe it's a duplicate - the SO community will vote on it.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister already done

Comment: @james My apologies, but I still don't see the columns you're talking about http://i.imgur.com/WLqc2cp.png Did you change the DNS recently, perhaps?

Comment: hmm... @MaximillianLaumeister it's just a heroku staging site that I pushed to. Here's what I'm seeing, with the URL on top http://i.imgur.com/jIlXKVR.jpg

Comment: @james Interesting, I'm only getting redirected when I visit in Chrome, not when I visit using Firefox. Can you test [your link](https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/request) in Chrome and see if you're getting redirected like I am?

Comment: Chrome works fine for me. I'm not sure why you're getting redirected....

Comment: @james It redirects me with all extensions disabled, but if I open it in incognito mode it doesn't redirect. Maybe it's a cookie thing?

Comment: So any redirect that is happening should redirect you on the same domain, because I"m using relative paths... When you get redirected, is it to hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com, or is it to lastmingear.com?

Comment: @james It redirects me to lastminergear.com.

Comment: That's very weird...  can you try going to https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com (the home page) and then pushing the "Gear up today" button? See if that keeps you at heroku's domain