# Fix top section of page

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Context, my page is divided like so:

- Left hand side (col-xs-8)

  - top part (class: `request-top`)
  - bottom part
- Right hand side (col-xs-4)

Both the top part of the left hand side and the right hand side should be fixed. The bottom part of the left hand side should scroll freely. I fixed the right hand side easily, but am having trouble fixing the top part of the left hand side.

What happens is that if I add `position:fixed;z-index:1000;` to the top part of the left hand side, it fixes, but then the `col-xs-8` gets overridden and the top part covers the right hand side. How can I fix but keep the `col-xs-8` setting? (short of a hack where I allow it to extend the full width, and then embed another `col-xs-8` and then just given the right side an even higher z-index)

Working staging version: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/request

Comment: There's a TON of it, and I'm not sure how much to post, so I put up the app instead. I feel it might also be easier to play around there? I'm  happy to post some, but what would you suggest?

Comment: pastebin.com or a fiddle at least

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row not expanding to full width of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897018/row-not-expanding-to-full-width-of-columns)

Comment: @RachelGallen sorry these are 2 totally different questions that just happen to be on the same page

Comment: Also I'm not sure a pastebin or fiddle is any less effective than the actual site

Answer (score 0):

It will take a step by step inspection..

I just make some changes,,Just try it and after that solve next problem..

```
.request-top {
background-color: #D8D8D8;
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
}
.request-bottom {
background-color: white;
padding-bottom: 3%;
position: relative;
}
.cart-section {
background-color: gray;
/* height: 100%; */
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
border-left: 7px ridge #939393;
right: 0;
}
.request-top {
background-color: #D8D8D8;
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
width: 85%;
}
```

Hi..

This is a web page done by me.Design a web page like this way.
There is a header a body section and there is 5-6 divs inside header for separate use.Look out the width difference between body section and header section.At header section width is maximum,and at the body section width is limited and div is aligned centered.

Inside the body I use one another div that I marked in this picture,and I also put separate scroll effect to divs.So they can individually move apart.The code I used here is to set a

```
    max-width: 292px;  //choose your dimension
    overflow: scroll;
```

[image: A sample web page]

I think it is better to use chrome browser.It has a feature that very useful to web developers.

First of all

Open your web page in chrome.

Right click (the portion that you want to make changes) and select Inspect element[Ctrl+Shift+i] in windows platform.

Then u can see like this..

[image: edited web page]

1 I mentioned here is code section and 
2 is css section.

The selected part is highligted in main screen (left side , in my case)

Then make necessary changes to css section that suits your web page and you can see the changes at the real time.

[**!! Please note that this is only for checking and viewing ,so if u make necessary changes,Please copy the edited code and paste it to your original source code also create a backup of your source code before make any changes** ]

Please vote if this is helpful to you..

Regds..

Comment: interesting, so does this imply that fix negates the columns of bootstrap and that I have to use a patch like setting the width to 85%?

Comment: @james The web page you designed is not only for your pc resolution.So if a client use a pc which has a lower resolution,the entire content get mis oriented.So keep in mind before design.  I edited my answer. Please go through it. Regds buddy..

Comment: thanks for sending along the example! So I agree that the webpage has to be for all pcs, but that's exactly why I'm afraid of using max-width. Because it's not very responsive, and even if I set media queries it would be more difficult than using Bootstrap's native columns. Are you saying there's no way of doing that?

Comment: Nothing is impossible if we are human..I will send you a web link..Try this..All the best..